# Example of a simple ring with a nonsimple subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Does there exist a simple ring with a nonsimple subring?

Comment: Of course you are right... and For an example in a noncommutative setting we can take the ring of quaternions (which is simple since it is a division ring) and it's subring only the elements with integer coefficients - Z[i,j,k]

Comment: @asafsh Please write what you finally discovered in a solution, so as to remove this question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z⊂Q is such an example.
For an example in a noncommutative setting we can take the ring of quaternions (which is simple since it is a division ring) and it's subring only the elements with integer coefficients - Z[i,j,k]